# cant fix the 'spring-boot-starter-parent-2.7.1 not found' error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am watching a tutorial so that I can start working with spring boot. after getting my .zip file from **https://start.spring.io/** I extract the file and then open it with intellij. When is finishes analyzing I get those 8 errors:

[image]

I have tried the Invalidate Caches solution but didn't work. Are there any other potential fixes?

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: Did you try to run maven clean and install?

Comment: ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2  Build #IC-213.6777.52

ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 11.0.13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; 
Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Windows 10 

ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: WelcomeScreen.OpenProject 

ERROR - minal.model.TerminalTextBuffer - Attempt to get line out of bounds: 14 >= 14 

those are the errors im getting in the idea.log @y.bedrov

Comment: The mvn clean install fixed the errors. Thank you. @Nemanja

Comment: This is common issue. I will post this as answer, maybe someone will find it usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `mvn clean` and `mvn install.` That should fix the issue.